# How to add friends to my roster in node xmpp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-xmpp

I want to add friends to my Spark roster.With this client i'm connected to node-xmpp server.How i should do this?I've saw events like `client.on('connect`)  or `client.on('stanza') .Is there a way to do this in this mode ?I think an event is executed when a a friend is added